# Unable to delete & update Entity using JPA on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsf, primefaces

I am doing a project with JSF (Primefaces), I load data from the Google Datastore and display it on p:dataTable, with Functions for Delete and Edit. But the delete doesnt work and no error messages, while the Edit using merge inserts new record. My code below.

**JSF PAGE**

```
 <h:form id="applicationsForm">
              <p:growl id="ngrowl" sticky="true" showDetail="true"/>
              <p:dataTable id="allEventsTable" var="events" value="#`{EventsMngtBean.events}">`

                  <p:column style="text-align: left; white-space: normal; width: 90%" headerText="Event Title">
                  <h:outputText value="#{events.eventTitle}" />
              </p:column>
              <p:column style="text-align: left; white-space: normal; width: 10%" headerText="Posted">
                  <h:outputText value="#{events.eventPostDate}">
                      <f:convertDateTime type="date"  dateStyle="short" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
                  </h:outputText>
              </p:column>

              <p:column style="width:4%">
                  <p:commandButton id="editButton" update=":memDetailForm" oncomplete="appDialog.show()" value="Edit" title="Edit">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{events}" target="#{EventsMngtBean.selectedEvent}" />
                </p:commandButton>

                  <p:commandButton id="showDialogButton" value="Delete" oncomplete="confirmation.show()" ajax="true" update=":delForm:confirmDialog">
                      <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{EventsMngtBean.selectedEvent}" value="#{events}" />
                </p:commandButton>
              </p:column>
          </p:dataTable>
      </h:form>

        <h:form id="delForm">
            <p:growl id="growl" sticky="true" showDetail="true"/>
            <p:confirmDialog id="confirmDialog" message="Are you sure to delete this event (#{EventsMngtBean.selectedEvent.eventTitle})?"
                header="Delete Event" severity="alert" widgetVar="confirmation">

            <p:commandButton id="confirm" value="Yes" update="growl" oncomplete="confirmation.hide()"
                         actionListener="#{EventsMngtBean.deleteEvent}" />
            <p:commandButton id="decline" value="No" onclick="confirmation.hide()" type="button" />
            </p:confirmDialog>
        </h:form>

        <h:form id="memDetailForm">
          <p:dialog header="Event Details!" widgetVar="appDialog" resizable="false" id="stdappDlg"
                    showEffect="fade" hideEffect="slide" modal="true">
              <p:scrollPanel mode="native" style="width: 900px; height: 550px;">
                  <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="display" style="margin:0 auto; padding: 5px;">
                  <p:column>
                      <p:outputLabel value="Event Title!" />
                  </p:column>
                  <p:column>
                      <p:inplace editor="true">
                      <p:inputText size="50" value="#{EventsMngtBean.selectedEvent.eventTitle}" />
                      </p:inplace>
                  </p:column>
                  <p:column>
                      <p:outputLabel value="Event Date!" />
                  </p:column>
                  <p:column>
                      <p:inplace editor="true">
                      <p:calendar value="#{EventsMngtBean.selectedEvent.eventDate}" />
                      </p:inplace>
                  </p:column>
                  <p:column>
                      <p:outputLabel value="Event Details!" />
                  </p:column>
                  <p:column>
                      <p:editor value="#{EventsMngtBean.selectedEvent.eventDetails.value}" />
                  </p:column>
                  <p:column>
                      <p:outputLabel value="Event Location!" />
                  </p:column>
                  <p:column>
                      <p:inplace editor="true">
                          <p:inputText size="50" value="#{EventsMngtBean.selectedEvent.eventLocation}" />
                      </p:inplace>
                  </p:column>
                  <p:column>
                      <p:outputLabel value="Posting Time!" />
                  </p:column>
                  <p:column>
                      <p:outputLabel value="#{EventsMngtBean.selectedEvent.eventPostDate}">
                          <f:convertDateTime type="date"  dateStyle="short" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm" />
                      </p:outputLabel>
                  </p:column>

                  <p:column style="width:4%">
                  <p:commandButton id="saveButton" update=":memDetailForm" oncomplete="appDialog.show()" value="Save Changes" title="Save">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{events}" target="#{EventsMngtBean.selectedEvent}" />
                  </p:commandButton>
                  </p:column>
              </p:panelGrid>
              </p:scrollPanel>
          </p:dialog>
        </h:form>
```

**THE JSF BEAN**

```
/*
```

* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

```
package com.wayah.nsa.admin.jsfbeans;

import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text;
import com.wayah.nsa.dbo.Event;
import com.wayah.nsa.dbo.providerimpl.EMFProvider;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Query;


/**
 *
 * @author MUHAMMAD
 */
public class EventsMngtBean {

    private Event selectedEvent = new Event();
    private List<Event> events = new ArrayList();
    private String value;
    /** Creates a new instance of EventsMngtBean */
    public EventsMngtBean() {
    }

    public List<Event> getEvents() {
        return events;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        value = selectedEvent.getEventDetails().getValue();
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        selectedEvent.setEventDetails(new Text(value));
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void setEvents(List<Event> events) {
        this.events = events;
    }

    public Event getSelectedEvent() {
        return selectedEvent;
    }

    public void setSelectedEvent(Event selectedEvent) {
        this.selectedEvent = selectedEvent;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void getAllEvents(){
        EntityManager em = EMFProvider.get().createEntityManager();
        Query query = em.createQuery("Select e From Events e");

        events = query.getResultList();
    }

    public void deleteEvent(ActionEvent ae){
        try{
        EntityManager em = EMFProvider.get().createEntityManager();
        System.out.println("EM: "+ em.isOpen());
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Event ev = new Event();
        ev.setEventDate(selectedEvent.getEventDate());
        ev.setEventDetails(selectedEvent.getEventDetails());
        ev.setEventLocation(selectedEvent.getEventLocation());
        ev.setEventPostDate(selectedEvent.getEventPostDate());
        ev.setEventTitle(selectedEvent.getEventTitle());
        ev.setKey(selectedEvent.getKey());

        em.remove(ev);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        //getAllEvents();

        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Deleted", "Event Deleted");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);

        }catch(Exception e){
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error when deleting event!", null);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void saveChanges(ActionEvent ae){
        try{
        EntityManager em = EMFProvider.get().createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        Event ev = new Event();

        ev.setEventDate(selectedEvent.getEventDate());
        ev.setEventDetails(selectedEvent.getEventDetails());
        ev.setEventLocation(selectedEvent.getEventLocation());
        ev.setEventPostDate(new Date());
        ev.setEventTitle(selectedEvent.getEventTitle());
        ev.setKey(selectedEvent.getKey());

        em.persist(ev);
        em.getTransaction().commit();


        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Saved", "Changes Saved!");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);

        }catch(Exception e){
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error when updating event!", null);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**THE ENTITY**

```
@Entity(name="Events")
public class Event implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Key keys;

private String eventTitle;
private Text eventDetails;
private String eventLocation;
@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
private Date eventDate;
@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
private Date eventPostDate;

public Key getKey() {
    return keys;
}

public void setKey(Key keys) {
    this.keys = keys;
}

public Date getEventDate() {
    return eventDate;
}

public void setEventDate(Date eventDate) {
    this.eventDate = eventDate;
}

public Text getEventDetails() {
    return eventDetails;
}

public void setEventDetails(Text eventDetails) {
    this.eventDetails = eventDetails;
}

public String getEventLocation() {
    return eventLocation;
}

public void setEventLocation(String eventLocation) {
    this.eventLocation = eventLocation;
}

public Date getEventPostDate() {
    return eventPostDate;
}

public void setEventPostDate(Date eventPostDate) {
    this.eventPostDate = eventPostDate;
}

public String getEventTitle() {
    return eventTitle;
}

public void setEventTitle(String eventTitle) {
    this.eventTitle = eventTitle;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (keys != null ? keys.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Event)) {
        return false;
    }
    Event other = (Event) object;
    if ((this.keys == null && other.keys != null) || (this.keys != null && !this.keys.equals(other.keys))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "com.wayah.nsa.dbo.Event[key=" + keys + "]";
}
```

Comment: can you share the error message which you were getting while deleting.

Comment: There is no any error message. The entity is just not deleted from the data store. Please.

Comment: What is the problem? Is the JSF action method invoked or not? If it is successfully invoked, then it's not a JSF problem at all, but just a JPA problem.

Comment: After running a test, i realised that the f:setPropertyActionListener set null to the selectedEvent property. Why is that